# Serving files for download with PHP - Stop multiple clicks

Tags: php, zip, download

I've got a "download.php" script which serves up files for download and the user can choose to download a ZIP file which is custom to them.. so needs to be generated on the fly.

The problem I've got, is if the user clicks the ZIP file 5 times in quick succession, the ZIP is generated 5 times on the server.

I need a method to only generate this on the first click, and not keep generating over and over again.

I do **not** want to "disable" the link permanently, because downloading the file again a few minutes later is fine if the user wants to, I just want to try and stop a malicious user hammering the download script to generate ZIPs constantly using server processing power.

Any ideas? I've been trying for hours and can't seem to get a solution which works :/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it an option to include a captcha code or similar to activate the download?  That would stop the fast clicking.

Comment: Not really unfortunately, kind of need it to be seamless so the user doesn't "realise".

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery to the front page to disable the button after the first click. Something like:

```
$("#button").click(fuction(e) {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "");
});
```

Also, you could cache the zip files for a certain amount of time so their only processed once for a thirty minute block, or some time frame.